# PHP calculation - why is 1+1=3?

Tags: php

The code my friend sends me is:

```
echo '1+1='.(1+1==2?2:1+2==2?3:2);
```

Why is it 3?

Comment: Read up on "operator binding", "operator precedence", and "order of operations". Some judiciously placed parentheses will solve the problem.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Ah... I see what it's doing. I was trying in JS.

Comment: As @GreatBigBore says, doing echo '1+1='.(1+1==2?2:(1+2==2?3:2)); prints `1+1=2`

Comment: Probably comes from this recent question on Code Golf - http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28892

Comment: possible duplicate of [nested php ternary trouble: ternary output != if - else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807454/nested-php-ternary-trouble-ternary-output-if-else), also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20559150/7586 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611985/understanding-nested-ternary-operators , and many others.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

PHP's evaluation of the ternary (or conditional) operator is a bit different from that of other languages.

```
1+1==2 ? 2 : 1+2==2 ? 3 : 2
```

Most languages (e.g. JavaScript) would evaluate this as:

```
(1+1==2) ? (2) : ( (1+2==2) ? (3) : (2) ) 
=> 2
```

PHP, however, evaluates this as:

```
( (1+1==2) ? (2) : (1+2==2) ) ? (3) : (2)
=> 3
```

So because `(1+1==2)` evaluates to true, the result of the first ternary expression evaluates to `2`, and that result is then passed to the second ternary expression, which evaluates to `3`.

This behavior is alluded to in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious…

The Wikipedia article on the [`?:` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#PHP) also mentions this:

> Due to an unfortunate error in the language grammar, the implementation of ?: in PHP uses the incorrect associativity when compared to other languages…
>
> The reason is that nesting two conditional operators produces an oversized condition with the last two options as its branches: `c1 ? o1 : c2 ? o2 : o3` is really `((c1 ? o1 : c2) ? o2 : o3)`. This is acknowledged and will probably not change.

- See also: [Bug #61915](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915)

Comment: I would rephrase "most languages" to "all other languages which feature ternary conditionals".

Comment: This is weird !! o__O

Comment: @haccks: Yeah, it's odd.  But PHP.  :P

Comment: `PHP's behaviour [...] is non-obvious`.  I always get a kick out of that line in the manual. Such a cute euphemism for "completely wrong".

Comment: Evaluates from left to right, instead of from right to left.

Comment: 'This is acknowledged and will probably not change.' it should and must,it's a BUG!

Comment: @mpm Added link to a 2012 bug report for completeness.

Comment: In other words: i.stack.imgur.com/U0w7J.jpg

Comment: @mpm If I had a dime for every part of PHP that should change but never will, I wouldn't have to use it ever again.