# PhP and java evaluate nested ? : differently

Tags: java, php

**in php**

```
$var =  true ? '1' : false ? '2' : false ? '3' : '4';
echo $var;
```

output is 3

**in Java**

```
char cond =  true ? '1' : false ? '2' : false ? '3' : '4';
System.out.println( cond );
```

output is 1

I completely understand how Java performed the logic. but i can't get how php will output 3. need help to understand how php actually evaluated that.

Comment: Yes. i tried run in both php and java

Comment: I just answered a question about this a few weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040555/php-calculation-why-is-11-3/24040704#24040704

Comment: That is funky! Expanding the if conditions gives the desired 1 - https://eval.in/168248. Thanks @p.s.w.g for your link aswell!

Comment: @Darren Simply putting parentheses around the latter clauses should work too: `true ? '1' : ( false ? '2' : ( false ? '3' : '4' ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precedence with parentheses

```
$var =  ((true ? '1' : false) ? '2' : false) ? '3' : '4';
echo $var;
```

Documentation: http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#example-138

Some explanation: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915